# what is the need for introducing ros industrial?

Tags: ros-industrial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What functionality from general ROS software was not sufficient and why did a need to introduce ROS -I arose ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256842/what-is-the-need-for-introducing-ros-industrial?/) by [sam26](https://answers.ros.org/users/29143/sam26/) on ROS Answers with karma: 231 on 2017-03-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check out the [ROS-I FAQ](http://rosindustrial.org/about/faq/).

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2017-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2